# ajax POST Request in android cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

How do I do POST request in ajax if I have this example request?

POST

Request URL: http://api.dev.mydomain.com/test/test1.json

Request Data = (access_token=[token here]&id=[id])

Here's what I tried but I always got failed.

tURL = Request URL

id = tid

```
function addGC(tURL, tid){

console.log(tURL);
console.log("GC ID:"+tid);

var url = tURL;

var postData = { access_token: localStorage.token, id: tid };

console.log("Final URL:"+url);
console.log("postData:"+postData);

return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,        
    data: postData, 
    timeout: 60 * 1000
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log("GC added.");
}).fail(function () {
    console.log("GC failed.");
});
```

}

Comment: It looks fine assuming that `localStorage.token` is in scope here.  what was the error?  in your `fail()`  callback please pass it three variables `function(a,b,c){}` and tell use what the values of `b` and `c` are.  Also you should look at what `a` was or check the browsers debugger.

Comment: @gillyspy Thanks I've found the problem now. The ID already exists that is why I receive error response. The callback in fail `function(a,b,c)` helps me a lot on debugging.